# React server side rendering - support for hashbang

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side, react-starter-kit

I'm porting my website from an Angular client side site to React with server side rendering. I'm using the React starter kit with the [universal-router](https://github.com/kriasoft/universal-router).

My customers have old links that use the hashbang form.
How can I support these old links in my new app?

e.g I want to redirect all `mydomain.com/#/path/to/page to` `mydomain.com/path/to/page`

Comment: The server never sees the hashbang routes.  I do not think you can support these old links with only server-side rendering.  You will have to run some code similar to Yura's answer on the client.

Comment: I ended up adding some code to the client side, see my comments to Yura's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(location.hash.indexOf('#')===0) {
    location.href = location.hash.replace('#','') 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I took your answer and modified it to my needs:   
    if(location.hash.indexOf('#')===0) {
        location.pathname = location.hash.replace('#','')
        location.hash = ""  
        history.replace(location);
    }